# Match whole, exact text line with Lua

Tags: string, lua, match

I'm looking for a little help on some Lua.  I need some code to match this exact line:

efs.test efs.test.gpg

Here's what I have so far, which matches "efs.test":

```
if string.match(a.message, "%a+%a+%a+.%%a+%a+%a+%a+") then
print(a.message)

else

print ("Does not match")
end
```

I've also tried this, which matches:

```
if string.match(a.message, "efs.test") then
print(a.message)

else

print ("Does not match")
end
```

But when I try to add the extra text my compiler errors with "Number expected, got string" when running this code:

```
if string.match(a.message, "efs.test", "efs") then
print(a.message)

else

print ("Does not match")
end
```

Any pointers would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm your looking to see if `efs.test efs.test.gpg` exists within `a.message`? or is it that your looking for `a.message` to match exactly `efs.test efs.test.gpg`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if string.match(a.message, "%a+%a+%a+.%%a+%a+%a+%a+") then
```

Firstly, this is a wrong use of *quantifiers*. From [PiL 20.2](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html):

> +    1 or more repetitions
>
> *    0 or more repetitions
>
> -    also 0 or more repetitions
>
> ? optional (0 or 1 occurrence)

In words, you try to match for unlimited %a+ after you already matched the full word with unlimited %a+

---

To match `efs.test efs.test.gpg` - we have 2 filenames I suppose, in a strict sense file names may contain only `%w` - alphanumeric characters (A-Za-z0-9). This would correctly match `efs.test`:

`string.match(message, "%w+%.%w+")`

Going one step further, match `efs.test` as filename and the following filename:

`string.match(message, "%w+%.%w+ %w+%.%w+%.gpg")`

While this would match both filenames, you would need to check if matched filenames are the same. We can go one step further yet:

`local file, gpgfile = string.match(message, "(%w+%.%w+) (%1%.gpg)")`

This pattern will return any `<filename> <filename>.gpg` where the filenames are equal.

With the use of capture-groups, we capture the filename: it will be returned as the first variable and further represented as **%1**. Then after the space char, we try to match for `%1` (captured filename) followed by `.gpg`. Since it's also enclosed in brackets, it will become the second captured group and returned as the second variable. Done!

PS: You may want to grab ".gpg" by case-insensitive [Gg][Pp][Gg] pattern.

PPS: File names may contain spaces, dashes, UTF-8 characters etc. E.g. [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) only forbids `\0` and `/` characters.

Answer (score 1):

`string.match` optional third argument is the index of the given string to start searching at.  If you are looking for exactly `efs.test efs.test.gpg` in that order with that given spacing, why not just use:

```
string.match(a.message, "efs%.test efs%.test%.gpg")
```

If you want to match the entire line containing that substring:

```
string.match(a.message, ".*efs%.test efs%.test%.gpg.*")
```

[For reference](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to match that exact line its way easier to just use:

```lua
if "efs.test efs.test.gpg" = a.message then
    print(a.message)
else
    print("string does not match!")
end
```

Of course this wouldn't find any other strings than this.
Another interpretation I see for your question is that you want to know if it has efs.test in the string, which you should be able to accomplish by doing:

```lua
if string.match(a.message, "%w+%.%w+") == "efs.test" then
    ...
end
```

Also, look into regex, it's basically the language Lua used to match strings with some exceptions.